# Which Framework do i use for checking on confirmed transaction on Bitcoin Blockchain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin

I'm writing a small gambling site where you can gamble with bitcoins.
As on the large currency exchange sites i want the user to log in. He then can create a new bitcoin address and send a amount of coins to that address.

When the transaction is six times confirmed the site should know about this status and give the user the sent amount of money on the site.

Now my question ist: Which Framework do i use.
The site will be written in Node.js. I have experience in working with the Blockchain Websocket API, but i think it is not reliable enough, so i looked into bitcoinjs.

What do you guys think? Which Framework is the best for determine these things?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are planning to use blockchain.info as your casino's wallet, I would stay away from their (or any other external) wallet management services, APIs, etc.

The traditional way of interfacing with bitcoin is by running [bitcoind](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) on your server, which is a fully fledged bitcoin client (and would need a full copy of the blockchain, so prepare for a big download there). You can communicate with it through its [JSON RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) and it will keep track of different wallets/addresses you have & their balances, as well make payments when that is necessary.

That said, there appears to be a native nodejs bitcoind alternative ("bitcoinjs" that you mentioned as well) which would probably be easier to set up. My personal recommendation would be **against** using an unofficial/alternative implementation. Bitcoind **is** bitcoin, you can't go wrong with it. Bitcoinjs is far more likely to have bugs than bitcoind, and will presumably be behind bitcoind on updates, which are sometimes crucial.

Here's a [getting-started-in-PHP tutorial](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro). I know you aren't going to use PHP, but the principles are all the same. Hope it helps.